# Mysql replication slave source ports?

Tags: mysql

Will the slave use source port 3006 and then connect to master on port 3306 to start replication? Or is random source port is being used to connect to master on 3306?

Comment: the source port is always a [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified, MySQL uses Port 3306.  That can be changed in various config files, `CHANGE MASTER`, startup command, etc.